# github for windows can't log in:username or password not correct?

Tags: github

I downloaded the latest version of github client. But when I try to log in I always failed, just like follow:
[image]

I am sure that my email and password are correct and I can log in successfully in the web.
So can anybody tell me what's wrong with my computer or my software?

Comment: Could there be an issue with your SSL settings?  The browser might be taking care of this automatically.

Comment: Just wild guessing that hust.edu.cn counts as an GitHub Enterprise account?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I never set something about ssl before. How can I check   my computer's ssl settings?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.0/user/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).  I'm not sure whether you need this.  You can also try to look at the log if there is one.

Comment: @rekire It is a email supplyed by our university.